# What would this scale be? Is it something Eastern?

Tags: scales, modal

[image]

Its kind of like a pentatonic scale, but some parts are chromatic. The note between the fourth and fifth is played. Moth minor and major seven are played. PLEASE HELP! thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is just the A minor [blues scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues_scale) with an added major seventh.